# Como é que eu posso abrir uma janela modal com window.open()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como é que eu posso abrir uma janela modal com `window.open()` no chrome, IE, opera, etc?

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: possível duplicata de [Janela modal no chrome](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77145/janela-modal-no-chrome)

Comment: Me diga, modal pra você é uma janela que bloqueia a janela que chama? Ou modal pra você é uma janela sem a barra de endereços? Ou seriam ambas?

Answer (score 8):

**Não** `window.open` não pode funcionar semelhante as janelas modais, **se o que você quer dizer** com modal é a nova janela bloquear a janela que chamou este modal ou ocultar a barra de endereços.

Antigamente existia a função [**`window.showModalDialog`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog) (ainda existe em alguns navegadores, mas está em desuso), exemplo:

```js
function modal()
{
    if (window.showModalDialog) {
      window.showModalDialog('http://pt.stackoverflow.com',
        [1, 4], "dialogwidth: 450; dialogheight: 300; resizable: yes");
    } else {
       alert("Seu navegador não suporta mais este método");
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="modal()">Testar</button>
```

Recentemente alguns navegadores com tecnologia webkit e blink, como o *Chrome 37+*, *Safari 6+* and *Opera 24+* adicionaram suporte ao método `.showModal();`, este método só funciona com a tag `<dialog>`, exemplo:

```js
function exemplo() { 
    document.getElementById("test").showModal(); 
}
```

```html
<dialog id="test">Olá mundo!</dialog>
<button onclick="exemplo()">Teste</button>
```

No entanto não existe "modal de verdade" que funcione em todos browsers, mas você pode utilizar jQuery ou Bootstrap pra simular a janela Modal (html+css+js), por exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Exemplo
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 E toca agora eu favoritar essa pergunta! :-) Depois da edição do @JorgeB e desta resposta, inclusive, retirei meu -1.

Comment: O Firefox e o ie não suportam o `showModal()`? Não se esqueçam que a maioria dos utilizadores ainda usa ie e agora o edge.

Comment: @JorgeB. Isto eu citei, só funciona no Webkit/Blink e por tal motivo falei sobre o uso do bootstrap, pois até aonde sei não existe uma alternativa cross-browser pra resolução.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, tem um polyfill que faz funcionar pelo menos no Firefox: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é legal, mas um pouco "exagerado", quero dizer, ele é bem mais que um pollyfill, ele tem mais coisas, o que na verdade torna o proposito todo um pouco além, claro que a parte de customizar é legal (o diferencial), mas olhando com calma pode se notar que ele substitui o dialog nativo e o .esm.js seria de fato o polyfill, mas o que "falharia" (entre aspas) na parte de "customização" dos navegadores com suporte nativo, quero dizer a ideia toda é legal, mas creio que possamos encontrar algo mais simples. Obrigado, em breve edito a resposta e adiciono o link de qualquer forma.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado na verdade acho o `<dialog>` nativo no Chrome péssimo, é totalmente "anti-intuitivo", para sair precisa do Esc, mas o navegador não informa nada, poderia ser bem melhor.

Answer (score 4):

O comando [window.open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) abre uma nova janela do navegador e te oferece algumas propriedades, como por exemplo:

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "_blank", "height=100, width=100, top=100, left=100");
```

Fazer com que esta janela haja como uma `modal` é questão de trabalhar com as `specs` que o comando te oferece e por exemplo remover a barra de status, remover a opção de *resize* e barras de rolagem, etc.

Todas as opções possíveis estão no link acima.

Comment: Eu já havia visto o w3 e não consegui fazer o window.open() abrir de forma Modal.

Comment: Mostre o seu código para eu saber o que você já fez.

Comment: Não tem código. O window.open() simplesmente não abre modal. Só quero saber se há como.

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade, não é possível fazer um modal com o window.open(), pois ele é uma função que abre outra página, nos caso você teria que utilizar o window.alert("Olá mundo!") para alertar o usuario, window.confirm("Deseja sair?") para perguntar o usuário e assim por diante, recomendo que utilize essa biblioteca em javascript e jquery: 
http://bootboxjs.com/

Muito fácil de ser utilizada e implementada no seu site.